# Java TCP Server/Client in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tcp

I have a question:

I had created a client app in Android Studio, and I need to know if it will work if the server was on Windows as a GUI program using Java.

so if the server was made using java in GUI on Windows and the client as a app on a Android smartphone... Will they connect successfully to each other?

Comment: This is not meant to be rude: but given the naivety of your question; I doubt that your programs will do what you expect. If you create a client and a server; and you define a protocol that they should use to communicate; and you make sure that the network infrastructure is as you want to be; then it doesn't matter where your server is running or in what language your client was written. If that doesn't help ... well, what kind of answer did you expect? Nobody besides you has insight into your code; and your descriptions are not enough to tell us anything. So, short answer: yes, maybe, no.

Comment: @GhostCat.Ok, thanks for your comment man and i'm really sorry about this but i do not have so much experience in Java, and i was worried too about answering my question.

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily, GhostCat only implies that you have to edit your question. Add better insights into it. We cannot help people who do not help themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both client and server comply with TCP protocol, they can interact with each other regardless of their underlying platforms, because all network protocols have their own principles and rules which must be obeyed by all platforms using them.

Also you shouldn't worry about medium-level byte ordering, because network has its own endianness which is big-endian and in various platforms they first convert their data to this endianness before sending it over medium. All these stuff are handled at OS level and you're not supposed to take care of them.